# Why exponentiation is considered elementary funtion?

Tags: special-functions, gamma-function

Why exponentiation and power function with non-integer power are considered elementary functions while some other functions like Bernoulli polynomials generalized to non-integer order, polylogarithm, Hurwitz zeta and polygamma are not?

Comment: [Definition of elementary function](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Elementary_Function)

Comment: The definition only lists which functions considered elementary.

Comment: The definition is rather arbitrary, and dictated by history. I think only a historian of mathematics can give a better answer than this, and it will probably come down to the same answer, just in more words.

Answer (score 1):

While I agree with Harald Hanche-Olsen that the definition of an elementary function is "rather arbitrary, and dictated by history", the inclusion of $x^y$ can be justified on the basis of

*Axiom 1  of elementary functions*: a function  that is elementary on rational numbers stays elementary after passing to reals by continuity.

For positive integers $m,n$ the operation $m^n$ comes naturally after $m+n$ and $mn$, as repeated multiplication. Solving simple algebraic equations $x^2=16$, $x^3=27$, etc naturally leads to $m^{1/n}$ as the inverse function of $m^n$. The obvious rules of exponentiation now define $x^{y}$ for rational $x,y$: for example, $(36/25)^{3/2}=216/125$. We can begin to work with these even if we still struggle with the meaning of irrationals such as $2^{1/2}$. In contrast, generalization of Bernoulli polynomials to *rational* orders does not happen quite as naturally. To say nothing of polylogarithm.

---

Axiom 1 does not justify the inclusion of trigonometric functions among elementary. For them we need  Euler's identity and

*Axiom 2 of elementary functions*: a function that is elementary on real numbers stays elementary after passing to complex numbers by analyticity.